# How to zip a folder and a file?

Tags: c#, zip

I want to zip a folder include 1 file and 1 sub folder (have some file in it).

[image]

```html
zip.AddDirectory(pathNotesFile, string.Empty);
zip.AddFile(pathTempFiles + csvFileName, string.Empty);
```

I have use DotNetZip library,
But after use these code above, the zip file which I get didn't have a sub folder.

[image]

Is there any way to create a zip file with a subfoler in it???

Comment: You should add how you use `zip` (is it a custom library? which one? SharpZipLib, DotNetZip, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DotNetZip you can do it without calling .AddDirectory() method :

```
zip.AddFile(pathTempFiles + csvFileName, directoryPathInArchive: "Attachments");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib

```
public static void ZipPath(string zipFilePath, string sourceDir, string pattern, bool withSubdirs, string password)
{
    FastZip fz = new FastZip();
    if (password != null)
        fz.Password = password;

    fz.CreateZip(zipFilePath, sourceDir, withSubdirs, pattern);
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: I don't use your library. But anyway, thank you for you help.